# Create two or more tables in a single stored procedure

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to create many tables in a single stored procedure?
I'm making a function to create tables, I pass the table name like a parameter, but I want to create 3 tables at once, this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_tables(t_name varchar(30))
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
    cond_a02_cabecera_id PRIMARY KEY,
    cond_a02_cabecera_nombre_archivo varchar(100),
    cond_a02_cabecera_centro varchar(100),
    cond_a02_cabecera_longitud int,
    cond_a02_cabecera_archivo_activo boolean,
    cond_a02_cabecera_fechae date,
    cond_a02_cabecera_fechad date
   )', t_name);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I'm using JDBC to create the database, I try put the "create table" again in the stored procedure but it only creates the first.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, It should be possible.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_tables(t_name character varying)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (a int);
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (a int);
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (a int);',
   t_name || 1, t_name || 2, t_name || 3);
END
$function$;
```

```
postgres=# select create_tables('foo');
┌───────────────┐
│ create_tables │
╞═══════════════╡
│               │
└───────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# \dt
        List of relations
┌────────┬──────┬───────┬───────┐
│ Schema │ Name │ Type  │ Owner │
╞════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ public │ foo1 │ table │ pavel │
│ public │ foo2 │ table │ pavel │
│ public │ foo3 │ table │ pavel │
└────────┴──────┴───────┴───────┘
(3 rows)
```